# Поиск ссылок, удовлетворяющих условию внутри блока

Tags: jquery

Как получить ссылки из блока `id="my_links"`, у которых значение атрибута `href` начинается с **"documents"**?

Пытаюсь таким способом, однако результата нет:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#my_links li a href:contains('documents')").css("fontWeight", "bold");
});
```

```html
<ul id="my_links">
    <li><a href="http://www.yamaha-motor.ru" target="_blank" id="superlink">Yamaha Motors Russia</a></li>
    <li><a href="documents/yamaha_fz6.PDF">Спецификация на мотоцикл Yamaha FZ6</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо,разобрался!

Comment: $('#my_links li a[href*="documents"]').css("fontWeight", "bold");

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_links li a[href*="documents"]').css("fontWeight", "bold");
})
```

Comment: в задаче - *начинается с "documents"*, поэтому     `$('#my_links a[href^=documents]');`